# Query filtering by week

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime

How to query (SELECT) in Postgresql, so that the results of a column with different dates, are between Sunday and Saturday of the current week.

Query fake example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datecolumn BETWEEN CURRENT WEEK
```

In another query, I have the number of the week in the year. How to make a SELECT for these dates, applying in the WHERE clause the specific week number in the specific year.

Query fake example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datecolumn BETWEEN WEEK15 FROM year 2020
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can use something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
  WHERE 
    EXTRACT(week FROM datecolumn) = EXTRACT(week FROM NOW())
    AND
    EXTRACT(isoyear FROM datecolumn) = EXTRACT(isoyear FROM NOW())
```

The `week` is ISO-8601 week number. By definition, ISO weeks start on Mondays and the first week of a year contains January 4 of that year. In other words, the first Thursday of a year is in week 1 of that year.

In the ISO week-numbering system, it is possible for early-January dates to be part of the 52nd or 53rd week of the previous year, and for late-December dates to be part of the first week of the next year.

For example, 2005-01-01 is part of the 53rd week of year 2004, and 2006-01-01 is part of the 52nd week of year 2005, while 2012-12-31 is part of the first week of 2013.

It's recommended to use the `isoyear` field together with `week` to get consistent results.

If you need custom (non-ISO) week numbering - you will have to craft your own calculation.

Comment: For the week to start on Sunday, it worked that way. ```WHERE 
    EXTRACT(week FROM datecolumn +'1 day'::interval) = EXTRACT(week FROM NOW()+'1 day'::interval)```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following pair of conditions:

```
where 
    date_column >= current_date - extract(dow from current_date) * interval '1 day'
    and date_column < current_date - (extract(dow from current_date) - 8) * interval '1 day'
```

Postgres' `date_trunc(week, ...)` starts weeks on Monday, so we need something a little more complicated, using `extract(dow from ...)`, which returns `0` on Sundays.

The advantage of this approach is that it is SARGeable, since no function is applied to the column being filtered. This means that this would happily take advantage of an index on the date column.

Comment: Why use the asterisk before the interval? Interesting, as I hadn't seen it yet.

Comment: @misterxis: that’s actually a multiplication (`n * interval '1 day'` gives you an interval of n days).

Answer (score 0):

I would use `date_trunc()`, but like this.  For the current week:

```
where datecolumn >= date_trunc('week', now()) and
      datecolumn < date_trunc('week', now()) + interval '1 week'
```

For the nth week of the year, this is trickier.  I think this does what you want:

```
where datecolumn >= (date_trunc('week', now()) -
                     (extract(week from now()) - 1) * interval '1 week' +
                     <n> * interval '1 week'
                    ) and
      datecolumn < (date_trunc('week', now()) -
                     (extract(week from now()) - 1) * interval '1 week' +
                     (<n> + 1) * interval '1 week'
                    )
```

Both of these are structured so the computations are NOT on the columns, so they are compatible with using indexes.

Comment: I used number 1 instead of <n> and the return were the dates of the second week, but not problems. How change the year and the week make starting on Sundays?

Comment: @misterxis . . . You should probably ask another question.  "week of the year" is defined in Postgres based on the ISO standard of weeks starting on Monday.  You will need to explain what *you* mean by that.